# php get two different random array elements

Tags: php, arrays, random

From an array

```
 $my_array = array('a','b','c','d','e');
```

I want to get two DIFFERENT random elements.

With the following code:

```
 for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
    $random = array_rand($my_array);  # one random array element number
    $get_it = $my_array[$random];    # get the letter from the array
    echo $get_it;
 }
```

it is possible to get two times the same letter. I need to prevent this. I want to get always two different array elements. Can somebody tell me how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always remove the element that you selected the first time round, then you wouldn't pick it again. If you don't want to modify the array create a copy.

```
 for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
    $random = array_rand($my_array);  # one random array element number
    $get_it = $my_array[$random];    # get the letter from the array
    echo $get_it;

    unset($my_array[$random]);
 }
```

Comment: Why use a loop? Why not just get the first random value, remove it from the array then get the second? You don't need to remove the second.

Comment: I used the loop because it meant minimal changes to creativz's code. Plus it makes it easy to extend the code to pick an arbitrary number of elements

Answer (score 20):

[array_rand()](http://docs.php.net/array_rand) can take two parameters, the array and the number of (different) elements you want to pick.

> mixed array_rand  ( array $input  [, int $num_req = 1  ] )

```
$my_array = array('a','b','c','d','e');
foreach( array_rand($my_array, 2) as $key ) {
  echo $my_array[$key];
}
```

Comment: I like this one. However, according to the comments on php.net the order of the returned indices is not so random. +1 anyway ;)

Comment: @middus: is this still true for recent versions of php? There have been a number of complaints about some random functions, esp. on win32. I thought they have been (somewhat) fixed.

Comment: I don't actually know. I have not tested it myself.

Answer (score 9):

What about this?

```
$random = $my_array; // make a copy of the array
shuffle($random); // randomize the order
echo array_pop($random); // take the last element and remove it
echo array_pop($random); // s.a.
```

Comment: For very large arrays this can be pretty slow, though as you certainly don't have to shuffle the complete array just to get two elements.

Comment: That was not part of the spec ;).

Answer (score 4):

You can shuffle and then pick a slice of two. Use another variable if you want to keep the original array intact.

```
$your_array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
shuffle($your_array); // randomize the order
$your_array = array_slice($your_array, 0, 2); //pick 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(array_rand($arr, 2))) as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k:$v\n";
}

//or

list($a, $b) = array_values(array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(array_rand($arr, 2))));
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a simple function I use for pulling multiple random elements from an array.

```
function get_random_elements( $array, $limit=0 ){

    shuffle($array);

    if ( $limit > 0 ) {
        $array = array_splice($array, 0, $limit);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. Hopefully this helps anyone confused.

```
$originalArray = array( 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth' );
$newArray= $originalArray;
shuffle( $newArray);
for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
  echo $newArray[$i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the first random, then use a do..while loop to get the second:

```
$random1 = array_rand($my_array);
do {
    $random2 = array_rand($my_array);
} while($random1 == $random2);
```

This will keep looping until random2 is not the same as random1

Comment: @pheelicks It should work because array_rand returns an index and not the element itself.

Comment: It's not the most graceful solution (my money is on middus) but it does work. Any comments/reasons from the downvoters?